# How to create nested list in list

Tags: java

why this declaration

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A"))));
```

does not give me a nested ArrayList back? What i get is a list with one element ("A") inside.

Comment: `List<String>` is not a nested list definition. If you want nested lists you need to provide an appropriate generic parameter, e.g. `List<List<List<String>>>`. However, before doing this you should think hard about whether you actually need this or whether there's a better solution (I'd bet there is).

Comment: Hey Thomas, thank you. My intention was not to create a nested list. I just do not understand, how it works internaly. This part "new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A"))))" should create me a nested list, right?

Comment: @tembers what do you actually intend to create, more specifically than "a nested list"?

Comment: @Andy. Why do i get an ArrayList<String> back instead of ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>?

Comment: @tembers because you're using a copy constructor. But what are you *trying* to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a constructor `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`, which creates an `ArrayList` based on the elements in the collection, so you can call `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("A"));` to create an `ArrayList` with the single element `"A"` in it (this code can sometimes be seen when a mutable list with initial values is required, as `Arrays.asList()` cannot change size).

However the way you're adding new layers of `new ArrayList(` on top of that will call the same constructor, taking the elements from the collection and putting them into a single arraylist, instead of nesting them. So you can't use that constructor for creating nested lists.

Your code is equivalent to the following, and as you can see it will always stay just a list of Strings

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A"));
ls = new ArrayList<>(ls);
ls = new ArrayList<>(ls);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. So this is kind of recursion here: new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<> ?

Comment: @tembers well, not really recursion. It's the way the constructor works. If they had written it so that it didn't copy the elements of the list, but just added the list as a single element, it would nest. But it would be quite useless compared to the way it works now.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, this is the part i was missing ls = new ArrayList<>(ls);

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
List<List<String>> parent = new ArrayList<>();

// Initialize child array
List<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
child.add("one");
child.add("two");

parent.add(child);
```